# how to download or save a picture from a powerpoint ppt with python pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I am working on powerpoints using python.pptx, where I am struggling to save certain picture from a slide to local system.Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Until now : I am able to print the shape, But dont know how to save the picture as we do with presentation using prs.save.

```
prs =Presentation('mypath/myPowerpoint.pptx')
slide2 = prs.slides[1]       #i want to save picture in slide 2
pic = slide2.shapes[4]       # i have check shape 5 is the picture
print(pic.name)              # i am able to print the picture name
pic.save('Mypic.jpg')        #------ this didn't work --------
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image depicted in a `Picture` shape can be accessed using its `image` property. The Image object provides access to detailed properties of the image, including the bytes of the image file itself.

http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.picture.Picture.image

http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/image.html#pptx.parts.image.Image

So, for example:

```
with open('mypic.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pic.image.blob)
```

Comment: Thank you very much scanny. I have tried image.save but never tried this way. This works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Be sure to accept this answer if it answered your question. That's how respondents are rewarded for taking the time to answer your question.

Comment: Sure. I didnt know that. Thanks for the help again

Comment: @scanny is there any way to take snapshot of each slide?

Comment: @SharadPaghadal that's really a separate question Sharad. You can submit it as a new question.